# need to get the line number of a searched string in

Tags: find

```
find / -name "php.ini"
```

I know I can find the above command to get the exact location of the searched file. I need to find the string ***oci8*** in this file.

since I do not have access to the GUI, I cant use an editor to do this for me :( And because the file size is relatively big, I need to know what command do i have to use to get the line number of the first occurrence !?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the below `find` command which in-turn invoke the awk.

```
find / -name "php.ini" -exec awk '/oci8/{print NR; exit}' {} \;
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat php.ini
http://stackoverflow.com
foo oci8
oci8
$ find . -name "php.ini" -exec awk '/oci8/{print NR; exit}' {} \;
2
```

**Explanation:**

Search for the files inside the `.` current directory (*`/` means root directory*) with the name `php.ini`. If a file was found with that name mentioned then do or execute this `awk '/oci8/{print NR; exit}' {}` operation on the founded files.

`awk '/oci8/{print NR; exit}'`

Searches for the line which contains the string `oci8`. If it finds any, then it prints the corresponding line number (`print NR`) and suddenly exit (*`exit`*) out from searching further.

**Through Perl**

```
find / -name "php.ini" -exec perl -nle 'print $. and last if /oci8/;' {} \;
```

Comment: Glad it worked out..

Answer (score 3):

Use `grep` with `find`:

```
find / -name "php.ini" -exec grep -Hnm1 'oci8' {} +
```

[`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/grep.1.html) is meant for searching for patterns in files. The `-H` and `-n` flags enable printing the file name and the line number of the matching lines, respectively. The `-m` flag limits search to a certain number of matching lines, in this case, 1.

Comment: `i have to use to get the line number of the first occurrence`

Comment: @AvinashRaj I suppose you want the `-m1` flag for `grep`.